# Which servo motors for a precise but not powerful robotic arm?

Tags: arduino, robotics, servo

I've just got into electronics with an Arduino explorer kit from Oomlout and I have learned a lot about electronics so far, but now I want to start my first proper project. A robotic arm.

It should be precise but barely needs to lift any weight at all (a laser pen). I would like it to be 30cm or so long, it would have one servo at the bottom for rotating the whole arm left and right, another up and down, then two more to lift the other segments up and down. Does anyone have any recommendations on servo's I should use? They don't need to be fast or powerful, just precise. And, of course, being cheap will be a bonus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't necessarily start with motors right off the bat.  You have to look at your entire system.  How are you going to mount the motors, and where?  If you put a motor at every joint, you have to remember that you're increasing the payload requirements for each motor in the chain.

Think about whether or not your first project *really* needs to be so precise.  And how do you define precise?  Within 2mm?  0.5mm?  10 microns?  For gripping, maybe you can get away with a simple RC servo.  Now you've just reduced the payload for the other motors.

Antibacklash is very important, and you could use anti-backlash gears and nuts, or you could go a little simpler and cheaper with belts and one or more idler pulleys.  The potential advantage here is that you can move a motor off of a joint and have it somewhere else where the weight of the motor doesn't adversely affect the system.

I'd like to hear what others think about this, but ultimately your servo's precision is going to boil down to your encoder and the gearing in your system, and the quality of your servo controller.  So perhaps the motor doesn't need to be a Maxon or a MicroMo, but something less expensive that still lets you connect a high-resolution encoder.  While I am not a fan of stepper motors, you could even go with steppers and encoders, which would simplify the system further.

Comment: Okay thanks for this, it has made me realize that I have allot more to learn than I first thought. I'l do some reading because I don't even know what an encoder is :S

Comment: read up on quadrature encoders, since they are ubiquitous.  Basically, you have slits in a round disc, and an emitter-detector pair.  The slits are aligned 90 degrees out of phase so that you can tell which direction the disc is spinning.  You'll then have an IC that can decode these pulses into discrete "ticks", where each tick represents a fraction of a rotation.  Depending upon your gearing / lead, you can convert this directly into an amount of motion.

Comment: For quadrature decoding, you might find the HCTL-2020 to be a simple solution. It's a relatively antiquated chip, but it works well.

Answer (score 3):

You might start with motors made by the Swiss manufacturer [Maxon](http://www.maxonmotorusa.com/product_overview.html). They're used in high-end robotic arms. They're expensive when bought new, but you might be able to get them cheaper off Ebay if you just need a few.

You should also think about how you will measure position and connect the motor to the arm. A lot of your position error will be in the backlash in the mechanism you build, error in the position encoder, and flex in the arm itself. You might also google "harmonic drive" or "anti-backlash gears."

Comment: Thanks for this, but I think these are a little too professional for a beginner hobbyist like me, I suppose I should have made that clearer in my question.

Answer (score 1):

I like the idea of building first with cheap imprecise servos ( at less than 10 bucks each )  I think you will learn enough to justify the expense.  Putting the mass at the end of a 30 cm lever will greatly increase the load on the servo.  Consider using different servos in different places.  Using the smallest one at each place ( joint? ) that will do the job, that will lessen the load on the servo that has to move it.